# How to properly convert sc_lv to sc_uint?

Tags: systemc

For a project, I am trying to convert a value that I receive from an `sc_lv<8>` type input port to an `sc_uint<8>` type signal. By the way, the input port is connected to an `sc_signal_rv<8>` channel.

I tried casting the input data using this line :

```
sc_in< sc_lv<8> > data_in;

// Other declarations

sc_signal< sc_uint<8> > tx_data;

// Other declarations
// Assume that all else is properly declared

sc_uint<8> temp;
temp = (sc_uint<8>)data_in->read(); // Casting
tx_data.write(temp);
```

But I get this warning during simulation :

`Warning: (W211) sc_logic value 'Z' cannot be converted to bool`

I though of doing a case-by-case affect, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's a warning, it notices you about 4-value to 2-value converting, it would lose information. So warning is good to make you awaring that

Answer (score 0):

Agree with enchanter.
But, it is a good practice to have your program compile without any warning, in other words that warning is a question and you should answer by modifying your code with an explicit cast:

```
sc_uint<8> temp = static_cast< sc_uint<8> >( data_in->read() );
```